# pyspark delete Row in dataframe where Row fild length ==40000

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, row, pyspark

I have  `DataFrame[item: string, true_recoms: map<string,int>]`

With schema:

```
StructType(List(StructField(item,StringType,true),StructField(true_recoms,MapType(StringType,IntegerType,true),true)))
```

I want to delete a row where length of `recoms==40000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so elegant,but:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("stringLengthInt", lambda x: len(x),    IntegerType())
train = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM train HAVING len(true_recoms)<40000")
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(train, "train")
```

check:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT item , stringLengthInt(true_recoms) AS l FROM train ORDER BY -l ").collect()
```